# Do i need to convert an variable to Int when using Prepared Statement - PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO friend_request (ToUID, FromUID) VALUES (?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $fid, $uid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt))
  echo 'Request Sent';
else
  echo 'Something went wrong !';
```

In the above code i have written `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $fid, $uid);`
Should i convert `$fid = (int) $fid` to make any improvement ?

Is there really any difference between [ the data type of ToUID,FromUID in database is int ] ?

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $fid, $uid);  
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $fid, $uid);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and it's a good practice to let the database cast the values (as long has you have a good schema).